# R-Catching errors and converting to logical

Tags: r

I am writing a function f which has several error traps ie 2 error traps. When these errors occurs, I use stop() for each error. I am making another testing function test.f to check whether these error traps worked correctly or not. Is it possible to make a logical list checking whether each error trap is working correctly ie TRUE is returned if the error trap gives a stop error

For example,

```
f<-function(x=1,y){
  if(x<0){
    stop("x is negative")
   }
   if(missing(y)){
   stop("y is missing")
 }
}


test.f<-function(){
  check.x<-tryCatch(f(-1,10),error=function(e) e ) 
  check.y<-tryCatch(f(1,),error=function(e) e )
  ls<-c(check.x,check.y)
  ls2<-c()
  for( i in ls) {
    if(is(i,"error")){
    ls2<-c(ls2,TRUE)
    }else{
      ls2<-c(ls2,FALSE)
    }
  }
  print(is(check.x,"error"))
  return(ls)
}
```

observe that the results is not what is expected when I use a list but is as expected when I use a single element eg is(check.x, "error")

```
[1] TRUE
$message
[1] "x is negative"

$call
f(-1, 10)

$message
[1] "x is negative"

$call
f(-1, 10)
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `testthat` package? I'm having trouble understanding your code. Why are `check.x` and `check.y` defined identically - shouldn't they be different?

Comment: @Gregor You are correct. check.y is to test the case of a bad y input into function f. I have corrected it. I do not want to use packages. I just want a list of TRUE or FALSE values telling me whether a stop has happened or not.

Comment: So I expect that ls() contains TRUE and FALSE only but it gives me this named list

Comment: Some coercion takes place - when you use `c()` on `check.x` and `check.y` I think they get coerced to characters. If you do `ls = list(check.x, check.y)` that will be avoided. And then you can `ls2 = lapply(ls, is, "error")` to get your list of booleans. Use `sapply` instead of `lapply` if you want a vector rather than a list.